# How to overcome the FCBL_FIELD_COULD_BE_LOCAL issue in FindBugs?

Tags: java, hibernate, findbugs

In FindBugs, I am getting an issue like `FCBL_FIELD_COULD_BE_LOCAL` on the class name line of this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@Immutable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class RetrievableStudent extends BaseStudent
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private long studentId;

    @Column(name = "STUD_NOTE")
    private String studenetNote;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Description is "class defines fields that are used only as locals" as there are many local variables inside the class

Comment: where are you accessing your fields? in the `BaseDiagnosis` class? If so, could you provide that piece of code in base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to resolve that issue you need to **use** you fields somewhere in your class. What FindBugs is telling you is that your fields in your class are never used as the fields.

How you using your fields that were retrieved from database? Maybe you need to add `getters`? For now, your fields are useless (unless you don't using them with reflection, which is not good).

Comment: I agree. Getters are not there for the class and as per my requirement I dont need those getters in the same class. Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

My POJO has already getters setters, equals, hashcode.
It worked when I tried adding `@JsonProperty` annotation, as my POJO is built for API response purposes.
If the POJO is for ORM purposes (means database entity) the on getters and setters `@Column` annotation should work.